# Why we should re-assign values for a recycled convertView in getView()

Tags: c#, android, android-listview, xamarin

For example (Xamarin c# example, but concept is same for Android java also):
"data" is the class which holds the data

```
   public override View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
       if( convertView == null ){

           convertView = inflater.inflate(Resource.layout.my_list_item, parent, false);
       }
        //just for example , hence avoiding ViewHolder here
        var textView = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
        var imageView = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.feedImageView);

       text.Text = data.getText(position);
       imageView = GetImageAsynch(data.getURL(position));

       return convertView;
   }
```

Here for every rows in the list, both textView and imageView is added/refreshed, which is fine initially, however when user scrolling and when program start using the recycled views, why do we need to re-assign the values (text and image) again if it is already present in the recycled views, that would be an over head right? What if I do as below:

```
   public override View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
       if( convertView == null ){

           convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, parent, false);
       }
        //just for example , hence avoiding ViewHolder here
        var textView = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
        var imageView = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.feedImageView);

       //this means if (recycled) view is empty, then only update the view
       if(text.Text == "")
       {
         text.Text = data.getText(position);
         imageView = GetImageAsynch(data.getURL(position));
       }

       return convertView;
   }
```

This is working fine for me, but my concern is I didn't see any such pattern in many examples I see here or in the internet.

Thank you

Update: Added "data" class to have more clarity on the question

Comment: In your example, all the views are identical and are either in an "active" or "inactive" state depending on some text field. So yes, in your example, there is little need to recycle views. Of course, if your user has a very slow internet connection, then it would take a long time to update the images if they were not local to the device whereas if you recycled the view, the image could be updated instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a View is recycled, it's not necessarily for the *same* item of the `Adapter` (indeed, most of the time, it's not -- the most common example is "item goes outside the view at the top as you scroll down, is reinserted at the bottom"). That's why the values need to be reassigned, because they almost always depend on the value of `position`, which will not be the same as the last time this view was used.

Your example is a bit trivial insofar as the text of the image are always the same, but this is not the case in most usages of Adapter views.

Comment: I have edited my question to have some change in the code. So now my texts are different. I put that hardcoded value just as an example.
My idea is to reduce the image download if it was already downloaded and available in the recycled view. (in that case why should I download it again and assign it)

Comment: @shibin Nevertheless, the answer is the same. When the view was returned from `getView()`, it was for record (say, 2). Now it's being reused for record number 9. So you need to update the text and image displayed in it.

Comment: Thank you! I got it. Now what if I do as below:
`//suppose if text.Text is the id field
//this check will make sure that the reccylced view is matching with the current data
if(text.Text == data.getID(position))
{
  text.Text = data.getText(position);
  imageView = GetImageAsynch(data.getURL(position));
}`
I think this check should be OK?

Comment: @shibin Provided that texts never repeat themselves for different positions, yes.