# Android ListView showing only first 4 items on repeat

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a Fragment called ***User Management*** where I collect data from a server and display it in a ListView. It's also refreshable via `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

What happens is, if I get data on 1-4 users, it displays the data correctly. However, if I get data on more than 4 users, it displays the first 4 correctly, and instead of the fifth, it's the first one again, instead of the 6th, it's the second one and so on and so on.

I've tried everything I could think of, the adapter is getting the data correctly, the ListView is getting the adapter correctly, but for some reason, it peaks at 4 users displayed, and simply repeats them after that (the funny thing is, if I add a user and then refresh, it simply repeats the next user one more time in the list, so it's definitely aware of the change in user number)

***Can you help me finding the problem?***

**The java class:**

```
package com.softwarenation.jetfuel.fragments.userManagement;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase;
import com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView;
import com.softwarenation.jetfuel.R;
import com.softwarenation.jetfuel.activities.MainActivity;
import com.softwarenation.jetfuel.fragments.Stations;
import com.softwarenation.jetfuel.managers.JetfuelManager;
import com.softwarenation.jetfuel.managers.StatusManager;
import com.softwarenation.jetfuel.managers.UserManager;
import com.softwarenation.jetfuel.utility.Global;
import com.softwarenation.jetfuel.utility.GlobalConnection;
import com.softwarenation.jetfuel.utility.users.User_pictures;
import com.softwarenation.jetfuel.utility.users.Users_mana;

import org.nicktate.projectile.Method;
import org.nicktate.projectile.Projectile;
import org.nicktate.projectile.StringListener;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class UserManagement extends Fragment {
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    //private View refreshView;
    private Global font = new Global();
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<User_pictures> pictureses = new ArrayList<User_pictures>();
    private static boolean isfirst = false;


    private PullToRefreshListView pullToRefreshView;

    /**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }



    /**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_usermanagemnet, container, false);
        listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
      //  refreshView = (View) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe);

        //First time, we get the data from a server, then only display that data until the user calls for a refresh
        if(!StatusManager.getInstance().getUsermStatus()){
            UsersTask usersTask = new UsersTask();
            usersTask.execute();
        }else{
            setContent();
        }



        Button addUser = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.addUser_button);
        addUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Fragment fragment = new AddUser();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
            }
        });


        // Set a listener to be invoked when the list should be refreshed.




        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onRefresh() {
                                                                Log.e("start","onRefresh");
                                                                new GetDataTask().execute();
                                                            }
                                                        }
        );










       /* pullToRefreshView = (PullToRefreshListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh_listview);
        pullToRefreshView.bringToFront();
        pullToRefreshView.setOnRefreshListener(new PullToRefreshBase.OnRefreshListener<ListView>() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
                // Do work to refresh the list here.
                new GetDataTask().execute();
            }
        });*/

        return rootView;
    }


public void setOnRefreshListener (SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener listener){
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(listener);
}

public boolean isRefreshing(){
    return swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing();
}


    public void setRefreshing(boolean refreshing){
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(refreshing);
    }


    public SwipeRefreshLayout getSwipeRefreshLayout(){
        return swipeRefreshLayout;
    }


    //on refresh, get new data from the server
    private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(Void... voids) {Log.e("start","GetDataTask");
            UsersTask usersTask = new UsersTask();
            usersTask.execute();
            return new String[0];
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
            // Call onRefreshComplete when the list has been refreshed.
          //  pullToRefreshView.onRefreshComplete();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            MainActivity.setBackDisabled(false);
            Log.e("GetDataTask","completed");
        }
    }






    private class SampleItem {
        public String id;
        public String title;
        public String username;
        public String groupName;
        public int userPicture;
        public int editPicture;
        public int dPicture;
        public String activated;

        public SampleItem(String id, String title, String username, String groupName, int userPicture, int editPicture, int dPicture, String activated ) {
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
            this.username = username;
            this.groupName = groupName;
            this.userPicture = userPicture;
            this.editPicture = editPicture;
            this.dPicture = dPicture;
            this.activated = activated;
        }

    }




    static class ViewHolder {
        private String checkBox;
        private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
        private LinearLayout linearLayout;
        private RelativeLayout relativeLayout2;

        public void setCheckBox(String checkBox) {
            this.checkBox = checkBox;
        }

        public void setLinearLayout(LinearLayout linearLayout) {
            this.linearLayout = linearLayout;
        }

        public void setRelativeLayout(RelativeLayout relativeLayout) {
            this.relativeLayout = relativeLayout;
        }

        public void setRelativeLayout2(RelativeLayout relativeLayout2) {
            this.relativeLayout2 = relativeLayout2;
        }

        public LinearLayout getLinearLayout() {
            return linearLayout;
        }

        public RelativeLayout getRelativeLayout() {
            return relativeLayout;
        }

        public RelativeLayout getRelativeLayout2() {
            return relativeLayout2;
        }

        public RelativeLayout getCheckBox() {
            return relativeLayout;
        }

    }



    public class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SampleItem> {
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        public SampleAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, 0);
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_usermana, null);


                ImageView userPicture = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.userpicture);
                userPicture.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getItem(position).userPicture));

                TextView title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
                font.setFont(title, 3, getActivity());
                title.setText(getItem(position).title);

                TextView username = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
                font.setFont(username, 2, getActivity());
                username.setText(getItem(position).username);

                TextView groupname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupName);
                font.setFont(groupname, 2, getActivity());
                groupname.setText(getItem(position).groupName);

                ImageView useredit = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editbutton);
                useredit.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getItem(position).editPicture));
                useredit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("user_id", getItem(position).id);


                        Fragment fragment = new EditProfile();
                        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
                    }
                });

                /**---------------*/

                ImageView userdelate = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.deletebutton);
                userdelate.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getItem(position).dPicture));

                holder.setLinearLayout((LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lin_show_profile));



                //LinearLayout show = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lin_show_profile);
                holder.getLinearLayout().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("user_id", getItem(position).id);


                        Fragment fragment = new ShowProfile();
                        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
                    }
                });


                //
                holder.setRelativeLayout((RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.delate_user));
                //RelativeLayout delete_user = (RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.delate_user);
                holder.getRelativeLayout().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        DialogStop("Are you sure?", getItem(position).username, getActivity(), getItem(position).id);

                    }
                });
                //
                //holder.setCheckBox(getItem(position).activated);
                //
                /**---------------*/
                //Red or Blue background
                // RelativeLayout settings = (RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.settingsbutton);
                holder.setRelativeLayout2((RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.settingsbutton));

                //if(getItem(position).activated.equals("false")) {

                if (getItem(position).activated.equals("false")) {
                    holder.getLinearLayout().setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.discrepancy_background_red));
                    holder.getRelativeLayout().setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.discrepancy_background_red));
                    holder.getRelativeLayout2().setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.discrepancy_background_red));

                }

                //holder.setCheckBox(getItem(position).activated);
                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {

                convertView.getTag();

            }


            return convertView;
        }

    }




    public void DialogStop(String title, String message,Context context, final String id){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //dialog.cancel();

                        DeleteTask deleteTask = new DeleteTask();
                        deleteTask.execute(id);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();
    }



    private class DeleteTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String response = null;

            try {
                response = new GlobalConnection().DELETE( getString(R.string.apicdeleteuser) + params[0].toString() );
                Log.v("response", response + "");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            Log.v("response", response + "");
        }
    }








    private class UsersTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Users_mana>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Users_mana> doInBackground(String... strings) {
            //Users_mana users = null;
            String response = null;
            ArrayList<Users_mana> users_manas = null;

            try{Log.e("start","GET via GlobalConnection()");
                response = new GlobalConnection().GET( getString(R.string.apiusers));
                users_manas = new Gson().fromJson(response, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Users_mana>>(){}.getType());
                Log.e("start","setUsers_mana");
                UserManager.getInstance().setUsers_mana(users_manas);


            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("response error", e.getMessage().toString());
            }

            return users_manas;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Users_mana> response) {

            if(!response.isEmpty()) {Log.e("start","setContent()");
                setContent();
                StatusManager.getInstance().setUsermStatus(true);
                Log.e("UsermStatus:",String.valueOf(StatusManager.getInstance().getUsermStatus()));
            }

            super.onPostExecute(response);
        }

    }




    private void setContent(){
        SampleAdapter adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity());

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        try {
            if (!UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().isEmpty()) {

                for (int i = 0; i < UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().size(); i++) {

Log.e("adding to adapter:",UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).firstName + " " + UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).lastName + "" + UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).id + "" + UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).username + "group:" + UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).group);
                    adapter.add(new SampleItem(
                            UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).id
                            , UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).firstName + " " + UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).lastName
                            , UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).username
                            , UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).group
                            , R.drawable.users_test
                            , R.drawable.settings
                            , R.drawable.delete
                            , UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).activated
                    ));

                }

                listView.setAdapter(adapter);Log.e("setting","ListView");
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("error setContent", e.getMessage().toString());
        }

    }


    /*
    private class PicturesTask extends AsyncTask<String, String ,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            //String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                for(int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
                    if(UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).photo != null) {

                        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(getString(R.string.jetfuel_url ) + UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).username).openStream();
                        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

                        pictureses.add(new User_pictures(mIcon11, UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).username, UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).id));
                        UserManager.getInstance().setUserPictureses(pictureses);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            if(!UserManager.getInstance().getUserPictureses().isEmpty()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < UserManager.getInstance().getUserPictureses().size(); i++) {
                    Log.v("pictures", UserManager.getInstance().getUserPictureses().get(i).picture + "");
                }
            }
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }
    */







    /**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        //menu.removeItem(R.id.Station);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.Station:

                Fragment fragment = new Stations();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,     fragment).commit();

                return true;

            default:

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }

    }
    /**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

}
```

**The xml view:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">




<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue">







    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addUser_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/add_user"

        android:background="@drawable/button_yellow_background"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


    android:id="@+id/swipe">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge problem in your `SampleAdapter.getView()` method.

When you scroll down the `View` disappearing at the top of the screen is reused to be injected at the bottom. This reused `View` is the `convertView` you get as `getView` parameter.

As you code is, the reused view is injected with the exact same data (because `if (convertView == null) {` is always false when you scroll).

Images and texts are not updated.

When you scroll down, the element disappearing at the top just appears at the bottom, and so does others...

You should be doing something like:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_usermana, null);

        // The ViewHolder constructor should handle the mapping of its views
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    // Here you should only use holder as in:
    holder.userpicture.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getItem(position).userPicture));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method looks strange, and is perhaps suspect. I don't see getUsers_mana() defined anywhere in this sample code, so I don't know if it is the problem or not. For one, you should call that 'UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana()' and then 'get(i)' once each and store the results in variables.

```
private void setContent(){
    SampleAdapter adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity());

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    try {
        if (!UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().isEmpty()) {

            for (int i = 0; i < UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().size(); i++) {

Log.e("adding to adapter:",UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).firstName + " " + UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).lastName + "" + UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).id + "" + UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).username + "group:" + UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).group);
                adapter.add(new SampleItem(
                        UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).id
                        , UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).firstName + " " + UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).lastName
                        , UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).username
                        , UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).group
                        , R.drawable.users_test
                        , R.drawable.settings
                        , R.drawable.delete
                        , UserManager.getInstance().getUsers_mana().get(i).activated
                ));

            }

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);Log.e("setting","ListView");
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("error setContent", e.getMessage().toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: This code is ugly yeah. But the given code is the `UserManagement` class, not the `UserManager` one ;)

Comment: I have to say that I inherited the code from someone who was doing this project before me, so I'm still not handling it very well. :(
it doesn't return 4, it returns the expected results, adapter is filled with the appropriate users etc, it just doesn't show on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not doing anything in the

```
else {

            convertView.getTag();

        }
```

Check here

[Why we should re-assign values for a recycled convertView in getView()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681013/why-we-should-re-assign-values-for-a-recycled-convertview-in-getview)

You have to reassign values to the convertView with the data of the 5th roq, 6th row etc. otherwise it still contains the old data

Answer (score 0):

Remove the initialization of holder on the top and just put this line of code in the beginning of getView function.

```
ViewHolder holder = null;
```

You need to re initialize holder if its null and you need to update it with latest data if its not null.

Answer (score 0):

See  this sample it might help you

https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView